# getting 404 even aftr 48 hours - azure VM and azure CDN

Tags: azure, cdn

I have a LAMP based wordpress installation running on an azure VM. its working fine and publicly accessible.

I wanted to try azure CDN - Verizon for serving my images.

I made cdn, using the new resource manager, added my endpoint of filmycurry.com (my origin server). I am using http only, hence configured the same in endpoint.

My problem is that even  after **48 hours**. I still cant access any media using cdn. you may try the below links

working - vm based - http://filmycurry.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/yu-2.jpg

not working cdn - http://filmycurry.azureedge.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/yu-2.jpg

pls note, I had also configured the **path** correctly to /wp-content/uploads, since beginning.

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: sorry, azure was recommending asking here and their forums. I see similar questions here also, but ny problem still persists.